# Makes drawing animation of SVG image

Tags: animation, svg, draw

I'm trying to animate the below svg image, I tried a library called [Vivus](https://github.com/maxwellito/vivus) which makes drawing animation on SVG

```
new Vivus('mySvg', {duration: 200}, 300);
```

unfortunately it didn't work!

here is the image: https://svgshare.com/i/WMH.svg  (sorry it's big to fit in the post as an inline svg)

The svg image has an id "mySvg" and it looks like this (it has no path it's based on base64 xlink:href):

```
<svg  id="mySvg"  version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="640px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 640 400" enable-background="new 0 0 640 400" xml:space="preserve">  <image id="image0" width="640" height="400" x="0" y="0"
    xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...
</svg>
```

Regardless the library or the technique used, I just want to make the image animated, that would be awesome if can be done via pure JS but with a library is ok too

Comment: That PNG is a binary image, it doesnt have  any stroke-dashoffsets vivus can animate

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I just realized this :( is it possible to turn a png to a vector with stroke-dashoffsets?

Comment: That is the holy png2svg grail